# What is the tool/method behind training a voice control model for Arduino?

Tags: speech-recognition

I just saw this [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z4Az6-MwPJ4&ab_channel=ScienceBuddies) link about a voice controller module that can recognize some sentences and perform an action.

So what's the math behind this?
Is it Support Vector Machine, Deep Neural Networks, MFCC, PCA, LDA? Or non of them?